# Python script cannot copy to a temporary location when install .run file via subprocess popen

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, popen

I try to install an app (<file_name>.run) via `subprocess` library using `popen` on Linux machine.

```
        command = f"sh /opt/setup/file_name.run".split()
        p = Popen(['sudo', '-S'] + command, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
        _, _ = p.communicate()
        p.wait()
```

But I got the error: `Copying to a temporary location.../tmp/makeself..220225122542.59580/makeself: 403: exec: -title: not found`

I checked `makeself..220225122542.59580` in the `tmp` folder and it was created but was empty.

Also, I ran the same command which my code generates (`sudo sh /opt/setups/file_name.run`) via commandline and it was successfull:
[run via commandline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFZOa.png)

Comment: The error is from inside the file_name.run, so can you please provide more details.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.